# Throwing my own validation message with custom CSS | URL validation

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to render the error message in my HTML form when a non-url is submitted, as I need to be able to easily adjust the position and apply a CSS style.

The reason I am going through this and not just simply using `type=url`, as I do not like the standard chrome validation error message, and I want to throw my own beneath my form.

Currently, no error message is showing when a non-url is submitted, and there are no errors in my console. Any thoughts?

```js
function onInvalid(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById('errorMessage').innerText = "Yikes! That's not a valid URL";
}
```

```css
#errorMessage {
  display: none;
  color: #EB7051;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<form method="POST" id="Submit">
  <div class="inner-form">
    <div class="input-field first-wrap">
      <div class="svg-wrapper">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                    <path
                        d="M15.5 14h-.79l-.28-.27C15.41 12.59 16 11.11 16 9.5 16 5.91 13.09 3 9.5 3S3 5.91 3 9.5 5.91 16 9.5 16c1.61 0 3.09-.59 4.23-1.57l.27.28v.79l5 4.99L20.49 19l-4.99-5zm-6 0C7.01 14 5 11.99 5 9.5S7.01 5 9.5 5 14 7.01 14 9.5 11.99 14 9.5 14z "
                    ></path>
                </svg>
      </div>
      <input id="search" name="url" placeholder="Paste a domain here" type="url" required oninvalid="onInvalid(event)" />
    </div>

    <div class="input-field second-wrap">
      <button id="button" class="btn-search" onclick="searchIt()" value="press" type="submit">
                SEARCH
            </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p class="errorMessage" id="errorMessage">Yikes! That's not a valid URL.</p>
</form>
```

Could it be because the `display: none` ? I only want it to show when a non valid url (does not contain http:// or https://), and then disappear when a valid url is submitted

Edit of desired result:

[image]

Comment: @AlexanderChristophorov It is embedded in my html file. Not through a stylesheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. `display: none` is the culprit. And for hiding the error message when valid url is submitted, you'll just need to set the `innterText` as empty string (`''`) when the input is valid.

Here's my solution: https://jsfiddle.net/mqvynw3L/

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #errorMessage {
                color: #EB7051;
                font-size: 15px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" id="Submit">
            <div class="inner-form">
              <div class="input-field first-wrap">
                <div class="svg-wrapper">
                  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                              <path
                                  d="M15.5 14h-.79l-.28-.27C15.41 12.59 16 11.11 16 9.5 16 5.91 13.09 3 9.5 3S3 5.91 3 9.5 5.91 16 9.5 16c1.61 0 3.09-.59 4.23-1.57l.27.28v.79l5 4.99L20.49 19l-4.99-5zm-6 0C7.01 14 5 11.99 5 9.5S7.01 5 9.5 5 14 7.01 14 9.5 11.99 14 9.5 14z "
                              ></path>
                          </svg>
                </div>
                <input id="search" name="url" placeholder="Paste a domain here" type="url" required oninvalid="onInvalid(event)" />
              </div>
          
              <div class="input-field second-wrap">
                <button id="button" class="btn-search" onclick="searchIt()" value="press" type="submit">
                    SEARCH
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <p class="errorMessage" id="errorMessage"></p>
          </form>
    </body>
    <script>
        function runValidation() {
            const inputEl = document.getElementById('search');
            const errorEl = document.getElementById('errorMessage');

            console.log('Validating the input value >>>', inputEl.value);

            if (inputEl && typeof inputEl.checkValidity === 'function') {
                const isValid = inputEl.checkValidity();
                console.log('IsValid >>>', isValid);
                errorEl.innerText = !isValid ? "Yikes! That's not a valid URL" : '';
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        function searchIt(ev) {
            if (runValidation()) {
                console.log('Search it .>>');
            }
        }

        function onInvalid(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Since, `oninvalid` also runs only during submitting, it's best to create your own validation (I'm using the browser's native validator with `checkValidity`), and only execute your submit actions (eg: calling API) if the input is valid. This way you have more control over the logic and in case you decide to run the validation when the input changes, you can just call `runValidation` function for `onkeypress` event.

Comment: Thanks... it is working on yours, but not on mine. Can you please review it? Doesn't appear as if I missed anything... 

https://codepen.io/SteveyUSA/pen/jOVqBWL

Comment: You have 2 `searchIt` function. The later one over writes the one from my answer. That's why it isn't working

Comment: I had removed the second, and integreated the remaining code into the first, however no luck, I ended up receiving the chrome validation again. If you could assist here that would be amazing. Sorry for the hassle.....

Comment: I'm guessing you've also removed the `onInvalid` function from my answer. The `ev.preventDefault()` in that function is what prevents from showing that chrome validation. Can you please provide your final code snippet?

Comment: Nope, I did not remove it.... I just have not updated codepen.

Comment: Here is the new pen.... Any thoughts on what it should look like based on your feedback? https://codepen.io/SteveyUSA/pen/MWbypOB

Comment: You have a error in the console. You are declaring `form` (i.e. `let form = document.querySelector('form')`) twice. Just removing that solves it.

Here's the codepen: https://codepen.io/koiralakiran1/pen/oNYxZyg?editors=1010

Also, please accept the answer if it solves your question.